# How to convert high-level statement (math expression of two inputs) to assembly for an instruction set with one accumulator?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

R = (P<sup>2</sup>Q + 2Q)/(P – Q)

how to write assembly program from this and this is the instruction set
[image]

Im new to assembly language and I tried some YouTube videos I know little bit about how to do simple but how to do this when P, Q, R
variables are stored in 10, 11 and 12 memory locations.

I Want to know how to solve this and if anyone can suggest me to a good YouTube video how to do similar and advance task that be great

Comment: Try to turn the formula into a sequence of steps where each step does one arithmetic operation, i.e. each step is of the form `A = B op C`.  Can you do that?

Comment: Also, while it might not be totally clear from that table, the `(XX)` mean memory locations. Additional hint: you will probably need a temporary variable (but you can use `R` for that).

Comment: but how to deal with that power of P and Integers

Comment: `P^2=P*P` ... not sure what you mean with "and Integers"

Comment: I made something like this recently, and I found that if you convert it to RPN using something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm) you can easily convert to ASM math as you already have a stack etc.

Answer (score 4):

First, as background, you need to understand a bit of math, syntax and operator precedence, which typically is standardized in mathematics.

In mathematics, an expression like `2X` means `2*X`, which means `2` times `X`.

Further, an expression like `c+2d` mean `c` + `2*d`, where the multiplication has higher precedence than addition, so more completely means `c + (2*d)` — *this as opposed to `(c+2)*d`, which would be the case if the precedence of `+` were higher than (or equal to) `*`.*

For more on this see: [Three-Address Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-address_code), and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

---

That instruction set describes an [Accumulator Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulator_(computing)#Accumulator_machines), also known as a 1-operand machine.  Since each instruction can supply one operand, and since a binary operator requires 2 sources/operands, it will take two instructions to perform a binary operation, when both operands are in memory.

```
c + d
```

would be performed by

```
LDA c   # load copy of the value in c into the accumulator
ADA d   # add the value in d into the accumulator
```

The resulting sum `c+d` is left in the accumulator.

To sum

```
c + d + e
```

We need only append one more instruction:

```
LDA c
ADA d
ADA e
```

again, leaving the sum `c+d+e` in the accumulator.

---

To do something more complex like

```
(c + d) * (e - f)
```

You would start with the above for `c+d`, and then need to compute `e-f` as the second operand for the multiplication.

Computing `e-f` requires the accumulator, and will thus wipe out any existing computation result in the accumulator (replacing it with the subtraction `e-f`).

However, the accumulator is holding the sum: `c+d`.  So, once computed, that sum needs to be stored to a temporary variable before computing `e-f` — I'm calling this temporary variable `t` and storage for `t` needs to be reserved in the data section, just like for `c`,`d`, etc..

```
LDA c
ADA d
STA t

LDA e
SUB f
MUL t
```

leaving the result of `(c+d)*(e-f)` in the accumulator.

---

Note that the above sequence actually computes `(e-f)*(c+d)`, because `MUL t` is multiplying the accumulator *(holding `e-f`)*, by `t` *(holding `c+d`)* — but this is the same resulting value as the other expression, due to the [commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of multiplication.

Division is not commutative, so, to divide more attention need to be put to the order of the operands for using a `DIV`.

```
(c + d) / (e - f)
```

You would either:

Compute `e-f` first, then save that to temporary, say `t`, then compute `c+d` into the accumulator and `DIV t`, as follows:

```
LDA e
SUB f
STA t

LDA c
ADA d
DIV t     # acc / t, so, (c+d) in accumulator / (e-f) in t
```

Or else, compute `c+d`, and store in temporary, say `t1`, then compute `e-f` and store in temporary, say `t2`, then  compute `t1`/`t2`.

```
LDA c
ADA d
STA t1

LDA e
SUB f
STA t2

LDA t1
DIV t2
```

---

To compute something involving a constant like

```
c + 2
```

on this particular machine requires that the 2 is placed into a variable, here I'm calling it `two`, and you'll need to have something like `two: .word 2` somewhere in the data section of the program.

```
LDA c
ADA two
```

Now, `c+2` is in the accumulator.

*(On some other machines, there may be an immediate operand [addressing mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode), where a constant such as 2 can be used directly from the instruction without a variable holding that 2, but this machine has only the memory operand addressing mode)*

---

As others are noting, usage of constants in certain expressions does not have to require constants.  For example, `c`<sup>`2`</sup> can be done by `c*c`, and `2c` can be done by `c+c`.